# Facebook SDK not getting e-mail

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I've been annoyed about this all day. I've followed all documentation and read all questions on Stack Overflow on this—but I just can't get the damn e-mail address with the latest FB SDK.

My code is:

```
ImpLog(@"Signupweh...");
if(fbSession == nil) {
    fbSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:@"XXXX"
                                     permissions:@[@"email", @"user_birthday", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access"]
                                 defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
                                 urlSchemeSuffix:@"xxxx"
                              tokenCacheStrategy:nil];
    ImpLog(@"Setting active session");
    [FBSession setActiveSession:fbSession];
}
[FBSession setDefaultAppID:@"xxxx"];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_birthday", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

    ImpLog(@"Contents: %@ | Error: %@ | Denied: %@\n",session.description, error.description, session.declinedPermissions);
    if(status == FBSessionStateOpen || FBSessionStateCreated) {
        ImpLog(@"Open session!");
    } else {
        ImpLog(@"Not open");
    }

    FBRequest* loginRequest = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [loginRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* result, NSError *error) {

        NSDictionary* uData = (NSDictionary*)loginRequest;

        ImpLog(@"Got data:\n%@",result);
        ImpLog(@"Got me (%@) with mail: %@", result.name, result[@"email"]);
    }];

}];
```

I get

Got me (My name) with mail: (null).

Similarly, when i print the content of result (NSDictionary*), there's just no e-mail. As you can see, I request the email permission. The user_birthday permission works great as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to have a confirmed e-mail address to get the e-mail. Makes sense.